# Simple formula for determining date using week of month?

Tags: c#, datetime, calendar, formula

Given a standard piece of scheduling information, such as "the second Tuesday in June 2009" or "the last Friday in July 2009", what's the simplest and most efficient formula to translate that into a date?

**Inputs:**

- `w` = Week of month, enumeration (1st, 2nd,
  3rd, 4th or Last)
- `d` = Day of week, enum Sun through Sat
- `m` = Month, integer
- `y` = Year, integer

**EDIT (again)** - It doesn't matter what day the week begins on; I want to get the *w*th instance of *d* in the given month.  Thus the 2nd Sunday in June 2009 is 14 June, even though that technically falls in the 3rd week of June; similarly the 1st Sunday in June is 7 June, not null/exception.

Comment: You'll need additional information -- what day do "weeks" start on, Saturday, Sunday, or Monday?  What about months with five of the same weekday (no "Fifth?")

Comment: Edited - week begins on Sunday.  Take it as given that we don't need a "5th" week.

Comment: Based on your two example questions "2nd tuesday in Jun 09" and last "Friday in Jul 09", doesn't the week begin on whatever day of week the 1st of the month is?

Comment: Please see my 2nd edit - I've reversed my position from my comment above.

Comment: In other words, Charles, you are right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like:

```
static DateTime GetDate(int year, int month, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek,
        int weekOfMonth) {
    // TODO: some range checking (>0, for example)
    DateTime day = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
    while (day.DayOfWeek != dayOfWeek) day = day.AddDays(1);
    if (weekOfMonth > 0) {
        return day.AddDays(7 * (weekOfMonth - 1));
    } else { // treat as last
        DateTime last = day;
        while ((day = day.AddDays(7)).Month == last.Month) {
            last = day;
        }
        return last;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EDITED to fix bug when weekday asked for was same as dayof week of first of month.

2nd edit to fix issue disc' by Marc

```
static DateTime GetDate(int year, int month, 
                DayOfWeek weekDay, int week)
{  
    DateTime first = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
    int iDow = (int)weekday, iFirst = (int)first.DayOfWeek;
    int adjust = (7+iDow-iFirst)%7 - 7;
    return first.AddDays(7*week + adjust);
}
```

Comment: Should that be 7*(week-1)?  Even so, using that formula, "1st Sunday of June 2009" comes out to 31 May 2009.

Comment: well, no, cause the adddays would be subtraction of up to six days when asking for day of week with smaller enum value than the day of week of the 1st,  but was buggy when the dayofweek asked for was same as first of month...

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace date_using_week_of_month
{

    public class Example
    {
        public static DateTime WthDayDOfMonthM( int w, DayOfWeek d, DateTime month )
        {
            return first( d, month ).AddDays( 7 * (w - 1) );
        }

        private static DateTime first( DayOfWeek d, DateTime month )
        {
            DateTime first = new DateTime(
                month.Year, month.Month, 1 );
            while ( first.DayOfWeek != d )
            {
                first = first.AddDays( 1 );
            }
            return first;
        }
    }
}
```